# Optimize INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE operation

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, plpgsql, common-table-expression

I wonder if the following script can be optimized somehow. It does write a lot to disk because it deletes possibly up-to-date rows and reinserts them. I was thinking about applying something like "insert ... on duplicate key update" and found some possibilities for single-row updates but I don't know how to apply it in the context of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT query`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_member_search_index() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
   member_content_type_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
   member_content_type_id :=
      (SELECT id FROM django_content_type
       WHERE app_label='web' AND model='member');

   DELETE FROM watson_searchentry WHERE content_type_id = member_content_type_id;

   INSERT INTO watson_searchentry (engine_slug, content_type_id, object_id
                                 , object_id_int, title, description, content
                                 , url, meta_encoded)
   SELECT 'default',
         member_content_type_id,
         web_member.id,
         web_member.id,
         web_member.name,
         '',
         web_user.email||' '||web_member.normalized_name||' '||web_country.name,
         '',
         '{}'
   FROM web_member
   INNER JOIN web_user ON (web_member.user_id = web_user.id)
   INNER JOIN web_country ON (web_member.country_id = web_country.id)
   WHERE web_user.is_active=TRUE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**EDIT:** Schemas of `web_member`, `watson_searchentry`, `web_user`, `web_country`: http://pastebin.com/3tRVPPVi.

The main point is to update columns `title` and `content` in `watson_searchentry`. There is a trigger on the table that sets value of column `search_tsv` based on these columns.

`(content_type_id, object_id_int)` in `watson_searchentry` is unique pair in the table but atm the index is not present (there is no use for it).

This script should be run at most once a day for full rebuilds of search index and occasionally after importing some data.

Comment: Rewriting it in plain SQL seems feasible. (you don't need the `member_content_type_id` variable,, it can be obtained by an extra term in the delete and insert queries) WRT the upsert: just an update, followed by an insert (where not exists) does the trick. Or use a RETURNING construct.

Comment: Do you really mean `'default',`, or do you mean `DEFAULT` ? IOW: please add the table definitions.

Comment: @wildplasser: I really meant 'default'. I added some more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Modified table definition

If you really need those columns to be `NOT NULL` and you really need the string `'default'` as default for `engine_slug`, I would advice to introduce column defaults:

```
COLUMN           |          TYPE           |      Modifiers
-----------------+-------------------------+---------------------
 id              | INTEGER                 | NOT NULL DEFAULT ... 
 engine_slug     | CHARACTER VARYING(200)  | NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default'
 content_type_id | INTEGER                 | NOT NULL
 object_id       | text                    | NOT NULL
 object_id_int   | INTEGER                 |
 title           | CHARACTER VARYING(1000) | NOT NULL
 description     | text                    | NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
 content         | text                    | NOT NULL
 url             | CHARACTER VARYING(1000) | NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
 meta_encoded    | text                    | NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'
 search_tsv      | tsvector                | NOT NULL
 ...
```

DDL statement would be:

```
ALTER TABLE watson_searchentry ALTER COLUMN  engine_slug DEFAULT 'default';
```

Etc.

Then you don't have to insert those values manually every time.

Also: `object_id text NOT NULL,  object_id_int INTEGER`? That's odd. I guess you have your reasons ...

I'll go with your updated requirement:

> The main point is to update columns `title` and `content` in `watson_searchentry`

Of course, you **must** add a **UNIQUE** constraint to enforce your requirements:

```
ALTER TABLE watson_searchentry
ADD CONSTRAINT ws_uni UNIQUE (content_type_id, object_id_int)
```

The accompanying index will be used. By this query for starters.

BTW, I almost never use `varchar(n)` in Postgres. Just `text`. [Here's one reason.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792)

### Query with [data-modifying CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

This could be rewritten as a single SQL query with data-modifying common table expressions, also called "writeable" CTEs. Requires Postgres 9.1 or later.
Additionally, this query only deletes what has to be deleted, and updates what can be updated.

```
WITH  ctyp AS (
   SELECT id AS content_type_id
   FROM   django_content_type
   WHERE  app_label = 'web'
   AND    model = 'member'
   )
, sel AS (
   SELECT ctyp.content_type_id
         ,m.id       AS object_id_int
         ,m.id::text AS object_id       -- explicit cast!
         ,m.name     AS title
         ,concat_ws(' ', u.email,m.normalized_name,c.name) AS content
         -- other columns have column default now.
   FROM   web_user    u
   JOIN   web_member  m  ON m.user_id = u.id
   JOIN   web_country c  ON c.id = m.country_id
   CROSS  JOIN ctyp
   WHERE  u.is_active
   )
, del AS (     -- only if you want to del all other entries of same type
   DELETE FROM watson_searchentry w
   USING  ctyp
   WHERE  w.content_type_id = ctyp.content_type_id
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   sel
      WHERE  sel.object_id_int = w.object_id_int
      )
   )
, up AS (      -- update existing rows
   UPDATE watson_searchentry 
   SET    object_id = s.object_id
         ,title     = s.title
         ,content   = s.content
   FROM   sel s
   WHERE  w.content_type_id = s.content_type_id
   AND    w.object_id_int   = s.object_id_int
   )
               -- insert new rows
INSERT  INTO watson_searchentry (
        content_type_id, object_id_int, object_id, title, content)
SELECT  sel.*  -- safe to use, because col list is defined accordingly above
FROM    sel
LEFT    JOIN watson_searchentry w1 USING (content_type_id, object_id_int)
WHERE   w1.content_type_id IS NULL;
```

- The subquery on `django_content_type` always returns a single value? Otherwise, the `CROSS JOIN` might cause trouble.
- The first CTE `sel` gathers the rows to be inserted. Note how I pick *matching column names* to simplify things.
- In the CTE `del` I avoid deleting rows that can be updated.
- In the CTE `up` those rows are updated instead.
- Accordingly, I avoid inserting rows that were not deleted before in the final `INSERT`.

Can easily be wrapped into an SQL or PL/pgSQL function for repeated use.

Not secure for heavy concurrent use. Much better than the function you had, but still not 100% robust against concurrent writes. But that's not an issue according to your updated info.

Replacing the UPDATEs with DELETE and INSERT may or may not be a lot more expensive. Internally every UPDATE results in a new row version anyways, due to the [MVCC model](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc-intro.html).

### Speed first

If you don't really care about preserving old rows, your simpler approach may be faster: Delete everything and insert new rows. Also, wrapping into a plpgsql function saves a bit of planning overhead. Your function basically, with a couple of minor simplifications and observing the defaults added above:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_member_search_index()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ctype_id int := (
      SELECT id
      FROM   django_content_type
      WHERE  app_label='web'
      AND    model = 'member'
      );  -- you can assign at declaration time. saves another statement
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM watson_searchentry
   WHERE content_type_id = _ctype_id;

   INSERT INTO watson_searchentry
         (content_type_id, object_id, object_id_int, title, content)
   SELECT _ctype_id, m.id, m.id::int,m.name
         ,u.email || ' ' || m.normalized_name || ' ' || c.name
   FROM   web_member  m
   JOIN   web_user    u USING (user_id)
   JOIN   web_country c ON c.id = m.country_id
   WHERE  u.is_active;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I even refrain from using [`concat_ws()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER): It is safe against `NULL` values and simplifies code, but a bit slower than simple concatenation.

Also:

> There is a trigger on the table that sets value of column `search_tsv`
> based on these columns.

It would be faster to incorporate the logic into this function - if this is the only time the trigger is needed. Else, it's probably not worth the fuss.

Comment: Hey, you avoided the `RETURNING` construct. Good job (and a CTE as well!)

Comment: BTW, the `del` CTE is never referenced. Is there a typo in there, or am I mistreading somehow?

Comment: Never seen such a statement:). But I am getting error atm: `ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to character varying` around line 3. I have added some more info into my question.

Comment: Well, you did not show the table definitions, so Erwin had to do some guesswork. (not everyone knows the  django data model) You'll probably have to add a  to/from text/varchar somewhere.

Comment: @wildplasser: Data-modifying CTEs can be useful without ever being referenced. In the updated answer neither of the CTEs `up` or `del` are referenced. They just tap into the same CTE `sel`. One has to remember that these CTEs are executed in parallel, so not rely on a certain sequence of operations.

Comment: @clime: The error came from the missing type information in the first version. Would have needed explicit cast like `''::text`. That part is gone completely in the now updated version.

Comment: @erwin Have been off during weekend. I really appreciate your answer and gonna test it out now.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Except for some typos it works nicely (here is my version http://pastebin.com/YyDgm9Yv). The problem is that this query is actually a bit more resource consuming than the one in the question. It takes about 1,5 times longer and cpu utilization is also higher. Disk writes are not really better either (http://postimg.org/image/atsidhwft/).

Comment: @clime: Well, the new query does more work, separating updates from deletes. And CTEs are sometimes optimization barriers, and plpgsql functions save some planning overhead ... I added a version of your function that may be a bit faster and some more advice. And fixed some typos

Comment: Thanks man, you were right about the trigger, removing it reduces the time by 5 secs (from 44s to 39s). Otherwise there is not reallly a difference, which probably means that function cannot be significantly  optimized. Thanks for your help. I learned a lot.