# Assign update query value to variable in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, updates, plpgsql, upsert

I need to insert some rows to tables in PostgreSQL. But before inserting the row into table, I should check whether the record is existing or not by using update statement. If update statement returns 0 rows, then I can insert, otherwise I can skip that insertion. I should write SQL statements for this in .sql file in PostgreSQL.

How to achieve this?

In Oracle we have below format:

```
declare
  i number;
begin
  update employees set status = 'fired' where name like '%Bloggs';
  i := sql%rowcount;
IF i ==0 THEN
insert statement here
end
```

How can I achieve this in Postgres?

Comment: Can you please suggest me whether it is possible or not.

Comment: You want to match each column?

Comment: Got answer using GET DIAGNOSTICS l = ROW_COUNT; in postgre sql

Answer (score 1):

If **concurrency** is not a problem for you, and you want to do it in a plpgsql function, rather use the special variable `FOUND`:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN

UPDATE employees SET status = 'fired' WHERE ... ;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
   -- insert statement here
END IF;

END
$do$
```

Or use a data-modifying CTE:

- [Insert if not exists else update it in Netezza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458463/insert-if-not-exists-else-update-it-in-netezza/22460331#22460331)
- [Optimize INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413254/optimize-insert-update-delete-operation/19439591#19439591)

If concurrency is relevant, read up on proper UPSERT solutions.

- [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)