# django add model field manualy to postgres database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, postgresql-9.1, ddl

I can't use south and I don't have pgAdmin but I need to add new field to the model at the end of the model. I need to be:

```
new_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have ssh access and have psql user defined so I need syntax to add that field to the model db table. Does `ALTER TABLE store_products ADD COLUMN description text;` do the job? How to set max_length 200, blank and null to be true? postgresql 9.1, django 1.6.

Comment: why not use the south?  http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take `blank=True` and `null=True` to mean that empty strings and NULL values should be allowed. These are the defaults, you don't need to do anything extra.

For `max_length=200` you *could* use `varchar(200)` instead of `text`:

```
ALTER TABLE store_products ADD COLUMN description varchar(200);
```

But I generally prefer the data type [`text`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings) in combination with a [`CHECK` constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792):

```
ALTER TABLE store_products ADD COLUMN description text;
ALTER TABLE store_products ADD CONSTRAINT description_max200
CHECK (length(description) <= 200);
```