# (var)char as the type of the column for performance?

Tags: performance, postgresql, types, normalization, postgresql-9.2

I have a column called "status" in PostgreSQL. First it used to be "status_id" of type `integer`. The values were kept on client, so there was **no** table on the server called statuses where I'd keep those statuses and then do `inner join` with the first table.

I used to send the ids of the statuses from the client (they had the names on the client). However, at some point I understood I'd better make the server hold those statuses. Not in a separate table but in the first one and I want to make them strings. So the initial table will have a `status` column of type string (`varchar`, to be more specific). I read it wouldn't be that slow.

In general, is it a good idea? I suppose it is because doing `inner join` (in case I'd keep statuses in the separate table) each time is expensive as well as sending ids from the client.

1) The only concern I have is that the column `status` should be of type `char`, not `varchar`. It should make it more effective I suppose. Is that so?

2) If the first case is correct then I'm not sure I'll be able to name all the statuses using exactly the same amount of characters, let's say, 5 characters. Some of them might be longer, some shorter. How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**

It's not denationalization because I'm talking about 1 single table. There is no and has never been the second table called Statuses with the fields (id, status_name).

What I'm trying to convey is that I could use char(n) for status_name and also add index on it. Then it should be fast enough. However, it might be or not possible to name all the statuses with the certain (n) amount of characters and that's the only concern.

Comment: The process you are describing is denormalization of the Status column.  That will cause its own problems.  Are you sure you don't want to keep your "statuses" table?  Joins are relatively cheap on low-cardinality tables like that one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is not denormalization. it would be denormalization if I had 2 tables and still used the column "status" in the first table.

Comment: Then why is it being stored as `status_id` of type `integer`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, because it's an integer. And the string representations are stored on the client as an enum (Int, String) or Map if you will.

Comment: The right way to do that is a statuses table in the database, with status_id as the primary key.  But, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, the right way doesn't necessarily mean there must be "statuses" table because it, at least, will require constant inner joins. I can make status be status_id in the main table and that's it. The names of the statuses will be on the client, there won't be "statuses" table.

Comment: Nothing is ever a hard and fast rule, of course, but putting your enumerated values in a linking table is the way it's done, say, 95% of the time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, why would I put them in a different table if they are very unlikely to change? I'd better keep them on client.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ... though I tend to find that for this sort of thing, it's better to use `"char"` (not `char(n)`) as the key, i.e. a single character key. No performance difference or a small win, and it's way easier to read the result rows because you have one-character abbreviations. Enums can also be useful.

Comment: The real question you should be asking is "why not just put them in the database?" For the same reasons that you put anything else in the database: it's data, and you want it to be in only one place.  What if you need to write a report, or make another form?  You have to endlessly duplicate that list.  The database can handle these short lists very easily.  There are other reasons: see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14814429, and continue reading from there.

Comment: Oh, and if you're using anything but an automatically-generated number as a Primary Key or Foreign Key, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I am asking again: why do we have to have 2 tables instead of one which has only status_id, not status_name?

Comment: There are several good reasons for having lookup tables; check out the chat link I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so using char or varchar instead integer is good idea. It is hard to expect how much slower it will be than integer PK, but this design will be slower - impact will be more terrible when you will join larger tables. If you can, use ENUM types instead.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-enum.html

```
CREATE TYPE mood AS ENUM ('sad', 'ok', 'happy');

CREATE TABLE person (
    name text,
    current_mood mood
);
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Moe', 'happy');
SELECT * FROM person WHERE current_mood = 'happy';
 name | current_mood 
------+--------------
 Moe  | happy
(1 row)
```

PostgreSQL varchar and char types are very similar. Internal implementation is same - char can be (it is paradox) little bit slower due addition by spaces.

Comment: `I don't think so using char or varchar instead integer is good idea.` - if I add index on it, why not to use it?

Comment: using enum at the server side seems to be a good idea, though.

Comment: Index will not be used on small tables - and varchar comparation is slower than integer.

Comment: I don't have 2 tables. I have only one table.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go one step further. **Never** use the outdated data type [`char(n)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html), unless you know you have to (for compatibility or some rare exotic reason). The type is utterly useless in a modern database. Padding strings with blank characters is nonsense, and if you *have* to do it, you can do it in a cheaper fashion with [`rpad()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) on data retrieval.

```
SELECT rpad('short', 10) AS char_10_string;
```

`varchar` is basically the same as `text` and allows a length specifier: `varchar(n)`. I generally use just `text`. If I need to limit the length, I use a [`CHECK`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) constraint. [Here's one example, why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792)

Whenever you can use a simple `integer` (or [`enum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html)) instead, that's a bit smaller and faster in every respect. Consider [@Pavel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942707/939860) for `enum`.

As for:

> because doing `inner join` (...) each time is expensive

Well, it carries a small cost, but it's generally cheaper than redundantly saving text representation of the status instead of a much cheaper integer in the main table. That kind of rumor is spread by people having problems understanding the concept of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The `enum` type is a compromise here - for relatively static sets of values.

Comment: I do sometimes use `char(n)` for fixed width short codes, e.g. ISO codes. But more as a means for documentation than for any technical purpose. It makes the intention and constraints clearer (I think)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Well, that's a possible use-case. If you *know* the strings are never blank-padded anyway, then there's no harm. Violating strings don't raise an exception, though. I'd consider `text` with a `CHECK` constraint `length(foo) = n`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that's what I'm trying to convey in my question. I'd use char(n) but it might not always be possible. But maybe it might be.

Comment: I could use char(n) for "status" as @a_horse_with_no_name described. Why not? I'd add index on it. At least I'll get rid of inner join.

Comment: @Alex: Sure you could. It's just a terrible idea. Main table and indexes will bigger and slower. Character data has to take `COLLATION` into account for sorting. Changing a status requires to change all rows with that status, instead of a single row, etc.

Comment: I find that `"char"` can be useful. It's not the same as `char(1)` (also known as `character` or `bpchar`); `"char"` is a single character type, and can be quite handy. PostgreSQL specific, though. `char(n)` on the other hand is absolutely awful and should be avoided.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I *love* `"char"` as a very efficient poor man's "enum". Only a single byte, small, simple and fast. But it's not in the SQL standard, the syntax with the double-quote is a bit confusing and there is [only a scarce note in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE), so I am not sure I should advertise it.