# Recursive SQL query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

Scema:

```
Person(pid:int,
       name:char(20),
       predecessor:int -> Person.pid
      )
```

Example Table:

```
pid, name, predecessor
0,   'abc', NULL
1,   'bcd', 0
2,   'cde', 1
3,   'efg', NULL
4,   'fgh', 3
```

How do i find all successors of a Person 'abc'?

Desired Ouput:

```
name 
'bcd'
'cde'
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question, providing sample data and desired results.

Comment: Check the manual. It has examples for that: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by generating all the ancestors and then filtering them out.  The following is an example for your data:

```
with recursive cte(pid, lev, ancestor) as (
      select pid, 0, predecessor
      from person p 
      union all
      select cte.pid, lev + 1, p.predecessor
      from person p join
           cte
           on p.pid = cte.ancestor
     )
select p2.name
from cte join
     person p1
     on cte.ancestor = p1.pid join
     person p2
     on cte.pid = p2.pid
where p1.name = 'abc';
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/be05c/11) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate the rows you need (not *all* ancestors for all rows) in a [**recursive CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with recursive cte as (
   select p.pid, p.name, 1 AS lvl
   from   person a
   join   person p ON p.predecessor = a.pid
   where  a.name = 'abc'

   union all
   select p.pid, p.name, c.lvl + 1
   from   cte    c
   join   person p ON  p.predecessor = c.pid
   )
select name
from   cte
order  by lvl;
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/51945/7)

Aside: [You don't want to use `char(20)`. Just use `text`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942142/varchar-as-the-type-of-the-column-for-performance/22943052#22943052)