# bumping the character limit on a varchar field which is used in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, database-migration, rails-migrations, sql-view

I have the following Rails Migration:

```
 class ChangeCommentLength < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def up
     change_column :videos, :comment, :string, limit: 500
   end

   def down
     change_column :videos, :comment, :string, limit: 255
   end
 end
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error message:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
DETAIL:  rule _RETURN on -view- depends on column "comment"
```

Attempting to run the sql directly:

```
ALTER TABLE "videos" ALTER COLUMN "comment" TYPE character varying(500);
ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
DETAIL:  rule _RETURN on view -view- depends on column "comment"
```

I understand why this would usually be a problem (can't go modifying datatypes underneath existing views). However, how can I work around this given that I am not changing the column type, just the column limit?

Comment: How about writing the migrations in plain SQL. Or would that just result in the same SQL code generated by Rails and thus the same PG error?

Comment: I've made an attempt to run the sql directly through rails:dbconsole with the same result, and have ammended my post to reflect that

Comment: Can you drop and recreate the view? And while you're at it, go straight to `:text` so that you don't have to worry about the size (and toss in a CHECK if you do have a real length constraint to worry about).

Comment: Details for @mu's suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792