# Add serial value across multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, primary-key, common-table-expression

I have the following two tables in my Postgres database:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    Id       serial UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    Login    varchar(80) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Id,Login)
);

CREATE TABLE UserData (
    Id       serial PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Users (Id),
    Password varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Say, I add a new user with `INSERT INTO Users(Id, Login) VALUES(DEFAULT, 'John')` and also want to add `VALUES(id, 'john1980')` in `UserData` where `id` is John's new id.

How do I get that id? Running a query for something just freshly created seems superfluous. I have multiple such situations across the database. Maybe my design is flawed in general?

(I'm obviously not storing passwords like that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1) Fix your design

```
CREATE TABLE usr (
    usr_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   ,login  text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE userdata (
    usr_id   int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES usr
   ,password text NOT NULL
);
```

- Start by reading [the manual about identifiers and key words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

  - `user`  is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Never use it as identifier.
  - Use descriptive identifiers. `id` is useless.
  - Avoid mixed case identifiers.
- `serial` is meant for a unique column that can be pk on its own. No need for a multicolumn pk.
- The *referencing* column `userdata.usr_id` cannot be a serial, too. Use a plain `integer`.
- I am just using `text` instead of `varchar(n)`, that's optional. [More here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792)
- You might consider to merge the two tables into one ...

#### 2) Query to INSERT in both

Key is the [`RETURNING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) available for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, to return values from the current row immediately.
Best use in a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO usr(login)
   VALUES ('John')             -- just omit default columns
   RETURNING usr_id            -- return automatically generated usr_id
   )
INSERT INTO userdata (usr_id, password )
SELECT i.usr_id, 'john1980'
FROM   ins1 i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a trigger. The Id column of the newly inserted row can be accessed by the name NEW.Id.

**References**:

1. [CREATE TRIGGER documentation on PostgreSQL Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html)
2. [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)